# 'Highlight' the current day in a string of the days of the month

Tags: r, shiny

I've been working quite some time with R and shiny but I can't seem to figure this one out. I want to display all days of the month and highlight the current day. Let's say it is 2017-10-26. I would then like to display:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 **26** 27 28 29 30 31

I got this function to display the number of days of the current date, but don't know how to go from there:

```
numberOfDays <- function(date) {
m <- format(date, format="%m")

while (format(date, format="%m") == m) {
date <- date + 1
}

return(as.integer(format(date - 1, format="%d")))
}

date <- as.Date("2017-10-26", "%Y-%m-%d")
days <- numberOfDays(date)

seq(1, days, 1)
```

Which results in just:

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

But.. I want to highlight the day of the month it currently is.

Any help on how to go about this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close :

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  numberOfDays <- function(date) {
    m <- format(date, format="%m")

    while (format(date, format="%m") == m) {
      date <- date + 1
    }

    return(as.integer(format(date - 1, format="%d")))
  }

  date <- as.Date(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d")
  lastday_of_month <- numberOfDays(date)
  current_day <- as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%d"))
  before <- 1:(current_day-1)
  after <- (current_day+1):lastday_of_month

  output$days <- renderUI({
    div(
      paste(before, collapse = " "), tags$b(current_day), paste(after, collapse = " ")
    )
  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  uiOutput("days")
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I just couldnt figure it out. Was stuck on it for quite some time.